# JPA entity join column on composite key, with date as one of PK

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have to join two tables with ManyToOne relationship using JPA.

TABLE 1 -> manF

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "manf")
public class ManF {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ManFCompositeKey manFCompositeKey;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 10)
    private String manFName;

    @Column(name = "desc", length = 150)
    private String manFDesc;
}

@Embeddable
public class ManFCompositeKey {

    @Column(name = "man_code", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String manCode;

    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    private Date updTime;
}
```

TABLE 2 -> products

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Prod {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProdCompositeKey prodCompositeKey;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 10)
    private String prodName;

    @Column(name = "prod_desc", length = 150)
    private String prodDesc;

    // -> JoinColumn here.
    @Column(name = "man_code", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String manCode;
}

@Embeddable
public class ProdCompositeKey {

    @Column(name = "prod_code", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String prodCode;

    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    private Date updTime;
}
```

Now, manF(Table 1) can have many products(Table 2). Thus, for each row in product table, there can be same manFCode.
I intend to establish a join b/w T1 and T2 such that manCode column in products behaves as the FK for this table referenceing man_code of Table 1.

Below is the join condition I wrote:

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumns({
  @JoinColumn(name = "man_code", referencedColumnName = "man_code")
  })
  @Column(name = "man_code", length = 20, nullable = false)
  private ManF manF;
```

This should make sense(I thought), but threw an error, stating: *ManF not mapped to a single property.*

Now I can do this:

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumns({
  @JoinColumn(name = "man_code", referencedColumnName = "man_code")
  @JoinColumn(name = "update_time", referencedColumnName = "update_time")
  })
  @Column(name = "man_code", length = 20, nullable = false)
  private ManF manF;
```

But then I would be keeping a FK reference on the time, on which a ManF was inserted.

I need to know how can I join the two tables here such that I can create a FK reference on the man_code of ManF table and the man_code in the product (child) table.

Comment: (on the margin: I'v read @italo vera answer - don't want to downvote, but is far to be ideal) ... Your idea is possible with hard work, but I have strong opinion, 1. use PK/FK in basic integer with auto numeration, store user and date in "normal", othogonal columns 2. Many JPA/DB project goes to nonsense with manual DDL generation, manual inserts or updates, this breakes many rules, and destroys reason to use JPA (use low level JDBC mapper, few good exists)

Comment: WHY You want such data in keys?

Comment: (formal note on the margin)  IMO Date column needs @Temporal.... Maybe is not required by Hbernate implementation (???) but per standard

Comment: @JacekCz Sir don't worry about Auto Incrementing as I have taken care of it using Sequence Generator. The data type for PK (Eg: man_code) is alphanumeric like MAN001. I am taking care of it.

Comment: @JacekCz Also, I am using *@Temporal* for date, I did not show it here. Sorry for that.
Also, I am using date as PK because I want to add/insert any update for the data. For instance if, MAN001 is inserted at 'x' time and updated at 'y' time, I need both the entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hibernate [native query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html) and write the join condition. If that is not a option I would particularly change the embeddedId on Manf to a regular id and create a constraint in your db, to maintain integrity an use a regular joincolumn condition. Like this:

SQL: ALTER TABLE 'manf' ADD UNIQUE 'UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT'('man_code', 'update_time');

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "manf")
public class ManF {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQUENCE_NAME", sequenceName = "SEQUENCE_NAME", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQUENCE_NAME")
    @Column(name = "man_code", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String manCode;

    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    private Date updTime;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 10)
    private String manFName;

    @Column(name = "desc", length = 150)
    private String manFDesc;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Prod {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProdCompositeKey prodCompositeKey;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 10)
    private String prodName;

    @Column(name = "prod_desc", length = 150)
    private String prodDesc;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "man_code")
    private ManF manF;
}
```

Comment: Your code shows some problems, when start to break JPA philosophy, add next and next and next problem. Example (one of few): Sequence (autmagicallly produced integer) is probably not best initialize in "String manCode" field, I guess author want totally difeerent content of column.  Hard, hard work, wih low or negative effects

Comment: This does not solve the problem. I HAVE to use date as a PK, and I have explained the 'why' in reply to @JacekCz. I am using sequence generator for increment the ID which is working just fine. (We have implemented a separate table for for SequenceGenerator).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done, to achieve this. May be a hack.

I have put the man_code from from Table 1 (ManF), in the main class (it stays is the Embeddable as well). But in the ManF class I did something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "manf")
public class ManF {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ManFCompositeKey manFCompositeKey;

    *@Column(name = "man_code", insertable = false, updatable= false)
    private String manCode;*

    @Column(name = "name", length = 10)
    private String manFName;

    @Column(name = "desc", length = 150)
    private String manFDesc;
}

@Embeddable
public class ManFCompositeKey {

    @Column(name = "man_code", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String manCode;

    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    private Date updTime;
}
```

On the other hand, I have changed my Table 2 as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Prod {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProdCompositeKey prodCompositeKey;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 10)
    private String prodName;

    @Column(name = "prod_desc", length = 150)
    private String prodDesc;



    *@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "man_code", referencedColumnName = 
    "man_code")})
    private ManF manF;*

    *@Column(name = "man_code", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String manCode;*

    @Column(name = "man_code", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String manCode;
}

@Embeddable
public class ProdCompositeKey {

    @Column(name = "prod_code", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String prodCode;

    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    private Date updTime;
}
```

This is somehow working, but I have had to add a new variable in the Child table (here: manCode with insertable and updatabale as false)

I am not sure if this is the correct approach. Please, let me know if someone has a better and elegant idea to approach this issue.

Comment: The '*' mark shows the new code added to potentially solve the issue.